unknown smd component marked t15
i have a eMachines 443 motherboard with a problem...power is not going to the battery. i am trying to trace the circuit but have encountered some unknown components.
this is one of them - marked "t15"...a 3 pin transistor(?)
what is it and is there a site that has it in its list of markings?


The marking t15 will be a "NPN resistor-equipped transistor" - part number PDTC115EU from Nexperia or similar.

This is a small SC-70 (smaller than SOT-23) package, with markings indicated per the datasheet and shown in an example photograph of the part.


Image Source
